# Is there any sense in splitting tables apart to separate often accessed data from rarely accessed data?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Say I had a table with 60 odd columns, but 99% of the time I only SELECT 3 or 4 of them. Does it make sense to split the table into one 4 column table and one 56 column table with an 1 to 1 correspondence between rows. Will this save me anything? Is there a performance difference between fetching 1000 4-column rows from a 4 column table versus fetching 1000 4-column rows from a 60 column table?

I'm using "MySQL 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49 for debian-linux-gnu"

Comment: That would be an interesting thing to measure. Feel free to write a performance measuring script. ;-)

Comment: Is it MyISAM or InnoDB and how much of the table is indexed?

Comment: All those factors can be changed around easily enough, and I'm not locked to any of them. I'm working with InnoDB, a primary index, a unique index and a couple of normal indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other DBMS you can achieve this by *vertical partitioning*. Having such a feature you can split your table in several partitions vertically - means splitting by columns.

This has advantages over doing it manually as you want to do it. It does not destroy your table design and is transparent for the programmer writing SQLs for these tables.
The work is done on a lower level and that's good.

I would wait if you really need that extra performance. And maybe MySQL supports vertical partitioning one day or another. Do not destroy your table layout for this as long as you do not really have to.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your DB performance. If you have high cache hit ratio, so your table is cached, then there is not point in splitting the table. Only if for many of the selects from the table the DB needs to read the data from disks, then it might be a good idea.